# Hibernate Eclipse Unknown Entity (using javax.persistence.Entity)

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I have been trying and searching all day to solve the issue Unknown Entity in eclipse.
I am using separate .java and hbm.xml files.

My Entity class is Account.java

```
// default package
package com.mywebservice.domain;
// Generated Sep 9, 2013 3:55:42 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

/**
 * Account generated by hbm2java
 */


public class Account implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String uid;
    private String empId;
    private String password;
    private Integer status;
    private Integer roleId;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String details;
    private String email;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private Date dateModified;
    private String modifiedBy;
    private Integer efpRoleId;
    private Integer isEfp;
    private Integer deptId;
    private Boolean isEpp;
    private Boolean isPasswordNew;
    private Integer statusEpp;

    public Account() {
    }

    public Account(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Account(int id, String uid, String empId, String password,
            Integer status, Integer roleId, String name, String description,
            String details, String email, Date dateCreated, Date dateModified,
            String modifiedBy, Integer efpRoleId, Integer isEfp,
            Integer deptId, Boolean isEpp, Boolean isPasswordNew,
            Integer statusEpp) {
        this.id = id;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.empId = empId;
        this.password = password;
        this.status = status;
        this.roleId = roleId;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.details = details;
        this.email = email;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
        this.efpRoleId = efpRoleId;
        this.isEfp = isEfp;
        this.deptId = deptId;
        this.isEpp = isEpp;
        this.isPasswordNew = isPasswordNew;
        this.statusEpp = statusEpp;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return this.uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getEmpId() {
        return this.empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Integer getRoleId() {
        return this.roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(Integer roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return this.details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return this.dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public Date getDateModified() {
        return this.dateModified;
    }

    public void setDateModified(Date dateModified) {
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
    }

    public String getModifiedBy() {
        return this.modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    public Integer getEfpRoleId() {
        return this.efpRoleId;
    }

    public void setEfpRoleId(Integer efpRoleId) {
        this.efpRoleId = efpRoleId;
    }

    public Integer getIsEfp() {
        return this.isEfp;
    }

    public void setIsEfp(Integer isEfp) {
        this.isEfp = isEfp;
    }

    public Integer getDeptId() {
        return this.deptId;
    }

    public void setDeptId(Integer deptId) {
        this.deptId = deptId;
    }

    public Boolean getIsEpp() {
        return this.isEpp;
    }

    public void setIsEpp(Boolean isEpp) {
        this.isEpp = isEpp;
    }

    public Boolean getIsPasswordNew() {
        return this.isPasswordNew;
    }

    public void setIsPasswordNew(Boolean isPasswordNew) {
        this.isPasswordNew = isPasswordNew;
    }

    public Integer getStatusEpp() {
        return this.statusEpp;
    }

    public void setStatusEpp(Integer statusEpp) {
        this.statusEpp = statusEpp;
    }

}
```

And Account.hbm.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 9, 2013 3:55:42 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Account" table="ACCOUNT" schema="dbo" catalog="EPP">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="uid" type="string">
            <column name="UID" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="empId" type="string">
            <column name="EMP_ID" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="PASSWORD" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="status" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="STATUS" />
        </property>
        <property name="roleId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ROLE_ID" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="description" type="string">
            <column name="DESCRIPTION" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="details" type="string">
            <column name="DETAILS" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="EMAIL" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateCreated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="DATE_CREATED" length="23" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateModified" type="timestamp">
            <column name="DATE_MODIFIED" length="23" />
        </property>
        <property name="modifiedBy" type="string">
            <column name="MODIFIED_BY" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="efpRoleId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="EFP_ROLE_ID" />
        </property>
        <property name="isEfp" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="IS_EFP" />
        </property>
        <property name="deptId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="DEPT_ID" />
        </property>
        <property name="isEpp" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="IS_EPP" />
        </property>
        <property name="isPasswordNew" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="IS_PASSWORD_NEW" />
        </property>
        <property name="statusEpp" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="STATUS_EPP" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am creating my session factory in a util

```
package com.mywebservice.utils;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class SessionFactoryUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml

            //Configuration config = new Configuration();
            Configuration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
            sessionFactory = config.configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

and calling it from

```
package com.mywebservice.utils;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import com.mywebservice.domain.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.*;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        getAccount(session);

    }

    public static void getAccount(Session session) {
        Account acc = new Account();

        acc.setEmpId("123456789");

        session.save(acc);

        System.out.println("Saved!");
    }

}
```

Also, I have added the mapping of the class in my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">hrportal@123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://HQ-10063332D\SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=EPP</property>
<!--         <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property> -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>        

       <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

       <mapping class="com.mywebservice.domain.Account" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But still no luck.
Any clues ?

I am using:
Hibernate 3.5
JPA 2.0
Eclipse KEPLER

UPDATE:
My complete error stack trace is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.mywebservice.domain.Account
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1475)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:705)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.mywebservice.utils.HibernateTest.getAccount(HibernateTest.java:24)
    at com.mywebservice.utils.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:15)
```

Comment: You use `AnnotationConfiguration`(deprecated) without Annotations. You use `hibernate.cfg.xml` without `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure()`. Choose one way, both ways together wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the `package` attribute in your hibernate mapping. Try updating the mapping part in your `hbm` file, something like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.mywebservice.domain">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Account` class is in package `com.mywebservice.domain`, so in your `Account.hbm.xml` the `class` name should be `com.mywebservice.domain.Account` and not just `Account`

Comment: Updated the question. stack trace added

Answer (score 0):

I want to konw, if you use XML to config your bean, why you use annotationConfiguration to build you session, you can try it with annotation config. may works.

Comment: #jesse If i don't use AnnotationConfiguration object, it gives the exception "An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.mywebservice.domain.Account"/>"

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, so it may help anybody else in the future.

In my hibernate.cfg.xml the mapping should be like

```
<mapping resource="com/mywebservice/domain/Account.hbm.xml"></mapping>
```

instead of

```
<mapping class="com.mywebservice.domain.Account" />
```

Also after correcting my hibernate.cfg.xml, I got an error
"Unable to initiate default tuplizer" for which I had to add a library called javassist.jar and it worked :) 
Good luck